How to received typed getTransaction response with jsonParsed encoding?
Context:
I am using @solana/web3.js 2.0 to invoke the getTransaction RPC method with encoding: "jsonParsed". The transaction is expected to have SPL Token instructions (create, transferChecked).
Problem:
I can call the RPC method and receive the expected response, but Typescript is unable to discern whether the getTransaction response type is parsed or not
Code:
const response = await rpc
  .getTransaction(someTxSignature, { encoding: "jsonParsed" })
  .send({ abortSignal: abortController.signal }); // This works fine

response?.transaction.message.instructions.map((ix) => { 
   ix.parsed // Type error that 'parsed' does not exist.
});

The type hint for ix is:
(parameter) ix: Readonly<{
    parsed: {
        info?: object;
        type: string;
    };
    program: string;
    programId: Address;
    stackHeight?: number;
}> | Readonly<{
    accounts: readonly Address[];
    data: Base58EncodedBytes;
    programId: Address;
    stackHeight?: number;
}>

Is there some type narrowing I need to do to get the correct parsed typing? Is there another way to do this with 2.0? Thanks!

Despite you having asked the RPC to return you a parsed instruction, there's no guarantee that the RPC will be able to parse every instruction. Therefore, the type of the instruction is a union of ‘a parsed instruction’ and ‘an instruction that could not be parsed.’
If you assert the presence of the parsed property, TypeScript will select the member of the union that has parsed in it.
response?.transaction.message.instructions.map(ix => {
    const { programId, stackHeight } = ix;  // Available on all instructions.
    if ('parsed' in ix) {
        const { info, type } = ix.parsed;  // Available on parsed instructions.
    } else {
        const { accounts, data } = ix;  // Available on non-parsed instructions.
    }
});


This was the solution. Thanks for the explanation Steve!
